# Change language of the spring context with the parameter in the body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, locale, body-parser

I need to change the language of the spring context. The problem is that it doesn't reach me by header or by URL parameter. How could I read the parameter of the body and change it from the whole context?

EDIT:
The client sends the locale parameter in the request body. I need to capture that parameter and set the language in the spring context.
Body example:

```
{
  "name":"username",
  "locale": "en"
}
```

Comment: Add more details like which headers are you checking and how etc.

Comment: The spring context? How would you do that? I suspect you want to use/convert the used language for use with the `MessageSource`. Please provide the information (the request) that contains the needed fields.

Comment: I need it for the messageSource and for some decimal formats.